# git cli yes/no wrapper rename from "something" to "something" failed. should i try again?

Tags: git, permissions, rename

I’m trying to rename a folder in Git with no success. Renaming on file level works, e.g. renaming from “Test.txt”  to “Test1.txt” works perfectly. On the Folder level, it doesn’t work.

See below

```
DOMAIN+HOSTID ZAF27 ~/Documents/-GitHub-/ (Test Branch-Deploy)
$ git mv Specification SPECIFICATION
Rename from 'Specification' to 'SPECIFICATION/Specification' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Rename from 'Specification' to 'SPECIFICATION/Specification' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Rename from 'Specification' to 'SPECIFICATION/Specification' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Rename from 'Specification' to 'SPECIFICATION/Specification' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
fatal: renaming 'Specification' failed: Permission denied

DOMAIN+HOSTID ZAF27 ~/Documents/-GitHub-/ (Test Branch-Deploy)
```

Comment: you should add in details of what commands or code you were using to achieve the rename, and then folks should be able to help you with problem.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't know anything about directories – it tracks files. You could do what you need with:

```
mv Specification SPECIFICATION
git rm -r Specification
git add SPECIFICATION
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved now. Seems like the issue was related to "some" access privileges. After the access was granted , i have deleted my local folder and pulled it back from the server. Only this helped